# How does Share Spells work with animal companions for continuous effects?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, druid, ranger, animal-companions

Right okay so here's a question I'm hoping someone can provide clarity to under the D&D 3.5 rule set. I've used the PHB, DMG and the 3.0 Rules of the Game Animals Part 4 to research an answer though I'm no closer to a solution.

From the ranger or druid class ability animal companion, spells can be shared with the companion via the share spells ability. This is also true of magic items, from Rules of the Game Animals Part 4:

> You and your animal companion can share effects from magic items only if the effect is a spell that you can target on yourself. For example, you and your animal companion can share a barkskin spell cast from a wand, but cannot share the armor bonus from bracers of armor.

How does this apply to magic items with continuous ongoing effects? Say for example the character is wearing a Mantle of Spell Resistance granting the wearer spell resistance 21, the wearer approaches and stays within 5ft of his animal companion choosing to share his spells with the animal companion. Does the animal companion also receive spell resistance 21 provided the wearer stays within 5ft of his animal companion?

Or is the understanding that sharing spells is only applicable if the character casts a spell or produces some effect at the time or after the character approaches and remains within 5ft. For example the character is riding along on his animal companion heavy horse suddenly the ground beneath them gives and both the animal companion and the character plunge down a 30ft pit. But luckily the character is wearing a ring of feather falling and therefore the feather fall spell is activated and BOTH the character and the animal companion drift slowly and safely to the bottom?

Last example using the character and heavy horse animal companion again from above, the character and animal companion are riding along the trail when suddenly an orc shaman jumps out of the bushes and casts magic missile, the character is wearing a brooch of shielding which protects against magic missile however the orc shaman casts the spell at the horse. Does the shield spell effect of the brooch of shielding protect the horse?

All of the above examples use reactive spells or effects, the character hasn't actively cast a spell or produced an effect to share.

Hoping someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 3):

## Typically only a spell from a spell completion or spell trigger magic item can be shared because [share spells](http://dndsrd.net/druid.html#animal-companion-share-spell) requires *casting* the shared spell

The description of the [share spells](http://dndsrd.net/druid.html#animal-companion-share-spell) extraordinary ability says, in part, says, "At the druid's [or ranger's] option, she may have any spell (but not any spell-like ability) she casts upon herself also affect her animal companion" (*Player's Handbook* 36). Skip Williams's Rules of the Game Web column ["Animals (Part 4)"](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20070206a) doesn't change this when it says

> You and your animal companion can share effects from magic items only if the effect is a spell that you can target on yourself. For example, you and your animal companion can share a *barkskin* spell cast from a wand, but cannot share the armor bonus from *bracers of armor*.

The column's previous paragraph says, "To share a spell, you must cast the spell and you must select yourself as its target. The spell must have a target entry; you cannot share effect and area spells," and that's *really* important.

Neither [*brooch of shielding*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#brooch-of-shielding) (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 250) (1,500 gp; 0 lbs.), [*mantle of spell resistance*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#mantle-of-spell-resistance) (*DMG* 261) (90,000 gp; 0 lbs.) nor [*ring of feather falling*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsPRR.html#ring-of-feather-falling) (*DMG* 232) (2,200 gp; 0 lbs.) sees the animal companion's master actually cast a spell, so a master can't share those magic items' effects with an animal companion… much like how Williams says that the master can't share the effects of the [*bracers of armor*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#bracers-of-armor) (*DMG* 250) (1,000+ gp; 1 lb.).

This isn't a contradiction. In much the same way that slapping onto his wrists the *bracers of armor* is not the same as the wearer casting the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell [*mage armor*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsMtoO.html#mage-armor) [conj] (*Player's Handbook* 249), when the *ring of feather falling* activates, the wearer is not *himself* casting the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell the spell [*feather fall*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsFtoG.html#feather-fall) [trans] (*PH* 229). Instead, when the *ring* activates, the wearer does nothing and gains automatically the *feather fall* spell effect from the *ring*. Similarly, when a creature dons a *mantle of spell resistance*, this isn't the same as the creature casting upon itself the 5th-level cleric spell [*spell resistance*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#spell-resistance) [abjur] (*PH* 282), and when the creature pins to that *mantle* a *brooch of shielding*, this isn't the same as the creature casting upon itself the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell [*shield*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#shield) [abjur] (*PH* 278).

However, when an animal companion's master activates a *wand of [barkskin](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#barkskin)* [trans] (*PH* 203) (2nd-level spell at caster level 3) (90 gp/charge), the master is activating that *wand* to cast the spell *barkskin*, and that *barkskin* spell effect can be shared with the animal companion. (The *Dungeon Master's Guide* on [Wands](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsSSW.html#wands) actually says, "Wands use the spell trigger activation method, so *casting a spell from a wand* is usually a standard action that doesn’t provoke attacks of opportunity" (245 and emphasis mine).)

Spell completion items like scrolls and spell trigger items like staffs and wands are the usual magic items that literally allow their users to cast spells so that they can be shared with an animal companion, but some rare magic items that aren't spell completion or spell trigger magic items also allow their bearers to cast spells. For example, the [*shield of the sun*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsICA.html#the-shield-of-the-sun) (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 282 as *shield of Prator*) (major artifact; 15 lbs.) allows the bearer to cast spells like a level 20 paladin.

However, most other magic items—for example, all but the most obscure potions, the vast majority of magic armors and weapons, almost all wondrous items—are either use activated or command word activated and don't see their bearers casting spells, despite spell effects sometimes taking place when their command words are spoken or the items used.

Comment: What are you thoughts in regards to a Ring of Elemental Command (Air)  command word activated air walk spell is in effect wherein 'You can cast air walk on a specially trained mount so it can be ridden through the air. You can train a mount to move with the aid of air walk'?

Comment: @MichaelDorf The *ring* is a command word activated magic item so it's not casting a spell; that makes effects it generates ineligible for the share spells ability. Further, the *ring* says that—unlike the spell—its *air walk* ability only affects the *ring*'s wearer. So I'm pretty sure, combined, when the wearer speaks the *ring*'s command word, *only* the wearer can gain the *air walk* effect.

Comment: @MichaelDorf That said, is this the scenario from the table that caused the question? If it is, I recommend updating the question so that it can be addressed head on.

Comment: 1) According to Share Spells it doesn't need to be solely a spell, effects also qualify as eligible for sharing. 2) I don't know how it should be phrased as part of the original question as it's not a scenario instead it's a comment addressed to you as a counter point.

Comment: @MichaelDorf When you say *It doesn't need to be solely a spell* are you talking about how share spells says, "If the spell or effect has a duration…"? Because that really is preceded by, "[A]ny spell (but not any spell-like ability) she casts upon herself also affect her animal companion." (I think *spell or effect* is making a distinction between a spell like *cure light wounds* that has no ongoing effect and one like *mage armor* that has an ongoing effect, but *or effect* could also be legacy text from *3e* when spell-like abilities could be shared.)

Comment: In the PHB under Share spells 'If the spell or effect has a duration
other than instantaneous...' Hold on what does effect mean? Refer to Rules of the Game Animals Part 4 'You and your animal companion can share effects from magic items only if the effect is a spell that you can target on yourself.' Ring of feather fall is indeed an effect which is a spell that I could target on myself as is Air Walk from a Ring of Elemental Command (Air).

Comment: @MichaelDorf There's no good game definition of effect (q.v. [here](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=&alpha=E)); its definition is fluid depending on context. That's why I offered a few different possibilities. That's why I suggest treating that one word less legally and focusing on the part that says, "To share a spell, you must cast the spell and you must select yourself as its target." A *ring of feather falling* doesn't see the wearer cast a spell nor does it see the wearer pick the wearer as the target of a *feather fall* spell the wearer casts.

Comment: I'm not sure about that rationalization defining a magic item seeing and picking. Also do you think this question needs to edited for further clarity and if so how? Because it's warning me here about not having long interactions in the comments section.

Comment: @MichaelDorf The site frowns on, in comments, debate and conversation. Comments are supposed to help improve the answer. If you think there're issues that've gone unaddressed by answers, then the question should be updated to make those issues clear so that answers *can* address them. If you *just don't like* the answers so far and have one of your own that you think's better, it's totally legit to self-answer your own question. Both options work.

Comment: @MichaelDorf (Also, when my comment says, "A *ring of feather falling* doesn't see the wearer cast a spell nor does it see the wearer pick the wearer as the target of a *feather fall* spell the wearer casts," I don't mean the *ring* is seeing. I mean that the *ring* activating isn't casting a spell. That is, the *ring* activating doesn't mean the *ring*'s wearer can pick who is affected by the *feather fall* effect the ring generates, and that—among other reasons!—makes the *ring*'s effect ineligible for share spells.)

Comment: To be honest there's no answer that I like anymore than any other, I'm far more concerned with having other users share their opinion.

Comment: @MichaelDorf Have you considered posing your question also on one of these [forums?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/8610) The *Giant in the Playground* forums, for example, are active and good with this kind of stuff.

Comment: Thank you I will investigate that option.

Answer (score 0):

As an opinion, the wording, "a spell that you can target on yourself" implies that it has to be activated by conscious user choice. Even though a continuous effect item obviously targets the wearer or an area, it doesn't really have an activation- pick a target type effect.

Comment: What are your thoughts on a ring of feather fall which is activated immediately if the wearer falls more than 5 feet? Would you agree the distinction is dependent on the terms 'grants' and 'activated' contrast to mantle of spell resistance and if so does this grant pertain to a brooch of shielding rather than activate it when a magic missile is cast?

Comment: Not really. An item that activates automatically when a condition is met is no different from a continuous effect. The idea of activate is user action, a conscious choice, not item reaction.